# Prolog constraint for cyclical ascending list

Tags: list, prolog, clpfd

I want to formulate a constraint in SWI-Prolog, using CLP (FD, in particular), that a list is a cyclical ascending list.

By that I mean a regular Prolog list which is taken to represent a cyclical list, such that the list and all its rotations represent the same cyclical list. And the constraint is that one of those rotations is a strictly ascending list.

For example, for 8 variables, I could represent it like this:

```
cyclical_ascending([A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H]) :-
    B #> A,
    C #> B,
    D #> C,
    E #> D,
    F #> E,
    G #> F,
    H #> G,
    A #> H.
```

except that one of those constraints is bound to not hold, while all the others are to hold. And I don't know/care, which one.

How can this be done?

Comment: do you mean you have a sequence of N variables which _you know in advance_ is ascending, _after_ being rotated several times, and you want to find that rotated sequence? (also, isn't your K always N-1 ?)

Comment: Yes, that is a correct way to put it, it is enough to find that one rotated sequence (I haven't think about it like this). And in my case K is always N-1.

Comment: so do you know each of these variables' values in advance, or do you want to express the constraint that one if its rotated variants is sorted, before ever knowing their values?

Comment: I don't know the values in advance, finding those is another part of the program, where other constraints are also present. As you say, here I only want to express this additional constraint that these values must be on a 'circle', or that one of its rotated variants are sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways I've thought of defining a `cyclical_ascending` rule:

- A list is `cyclical_ascending` if one of the rotations of the list is
  ascending
- A list is `cyclical_ascending` if either (a) there are no adjacent pairs `X, Y` where `X >= Y`, or (b) there is only one such pair and `Head > Tail`.

I think the second definition leads to a more efficient solution, so I'll try that. We'll keep track of the head of the list, and keep count of whether there was a single

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

cyclical_ascending([]).     % Empty list is a degenerate cyclical ascending list
cyclical_ascending([H|T]) :-
    cyclical_ascending([H|T], H, 0).

cyclical_ascending([_], _, 0).      % List is ascending
cyclical_ascending([X], H, 1) :-    % A cycle of list is ascending
    X #< H.
cyclical_ascending([X,Y|T], H, C) :-
    X #< Y,
    cyclical_ascending([Y|T], H, C).
cyclical_ascending([X,Y|T], H, C) :-
    X #>= Y,
    C #< 1,
    C1 #= C + 1,
    cyclical_ascending([Y|T], H, C1).
```

Or another way to write it is to avoid the counter but use another auxiliary predicate:

```
cyclical_ascending([]).     % Empty list is a degenerate cyclical ascending list
cyclical_ascending([H|T]) :-
    cyclical_ascending([H|T], H).

cyclical_ascending([_], _).
cyclical_ascending([X,Y|T], H) :-
    X #< Y,
    cyclical_ascending([Y|T], H).
cyclical_ascending([X,Y|T], H) :-
    X #>= Y,
    cyclical_ascending1([Y|T], H).

cyclical_ascending1([X], H) :-
    X #< H.
cyclical_ascending1([X,Y|T], H) :-
    X #< Y,
    cyclical_ascending1([Y|T], H).
```

Trying a simple query:

```
2 ?- length(L, 4), L ins 1..4, cyclical_ascending(L).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4] ;
L = [2, 3, 4, 1] ;
L = [3, 4, 1, 2] ;
L = [4, 1, 2, 3] ;
false.

3 ?-
```

Comment: You generally cannot use a constraint such as `X #< Y` in the condition of an if-then-else. The if-then-else will often commit to the then-case, even when later bound reductions or instantiations make the constraint false.

Comment: @jschimpf thanks. I knew it smelt funny. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution for ECLiPSe, but you can use the same idea with SWI/clpfd.
For every pair `X,Y` of adjacent list elements, we compute a boolean `B` that is 0 if the pair is ascending, and 1 if it is not.  To satisfy your "cyclical ascending" condition, exactly one of the `Bs` must be 1.

```
:- lib(ic).

cycasc(Xs) :-
    Xs = [X1|_], append(Xs, [X1], Xs1),                      % for convenience, append the first element to the end of the list
    ( fromto(Xs1,[X,Y|Xs2],[Y|Xs2],[_]), foreach(B,Bs) do    % make a list of booleans that indicate non-ascending pairs
        B #= (X#>=Y)
    ),
    sum(Bs) #= 1.                                            % there must be exactly one
```

Sample run:

```
?- length(Xs, 4), Xs #:: 1..4, cycasc(Xs), labeling(Xs).
Xs = [1, 2, 3, 4]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 1, maybe more)
Xs = [2, 3, 4, 1]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 2, maybe more)
Xs = [3, 4, 1, 2]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 3, maybe more)
Xs = [4, 1, 2, 3]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 4)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - at the end I accepted an other one, because the question originally was about Prolog, and terms like 'fromto' or 'foreach' are ECLiPSe specific. But the logic in the answer is very good and I could never come up with that!